# Appium find element by 2 parameters in Java

Tags: java, appium

I use Appium with Java to automate tests for mobile application. I'm looking for a way to find element by 2 parameters. I.e. by `accessibilityId` and by `xPath` within this element. So really rough example to visualize what I mean

```
Element el = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("name").isDisplayed();
Assert.assertTrue(el.findElement(By.xPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='texty']")));
```

Is this correct way to do this? Is there a better way? Ideal would be one liner because it is easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isDisplayed() does not return MobileElement/WebElement it returns a Boolean so a valid way is something like mentioned below

```
WebElement el = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("name");
if (e1.isDisplayed()){
   WebElement e2 = el.findElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='texty']"))
}
Assert.assertTrue(e2.isDisplayed());
```

You can chain any number of findElement e.g.

```
WebElement innerElement = 
      driver.findElement(By.AccessbilityID("someID"))
            .findElement(By.xpath("someXpath"))
            .findElement(By.cssSelector(".aValidCSSClass"));
```

If you use findElements you have to use it like this as it return List of WebElement or List of MobileElement

```
WebElement innerElement = 
      driver.findElements(By.AccessbilityID("someID"))
            .get(2)  //get 2nd element
            .findElements(By.xpath("someXpath"))
             .get(1) //get 1st element
            .findElement(By.cssSelector(".aValidCSSClass"));
```